# Edittext with multiple images and clicklistener

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I have a scenario in which I have to to add text and multiple images, something like below

"fooo bar [image] lorem ipsum [image] somtext.

and all these images have clicklisteners so I can know which image is being clicked.

Till now I am able to place images but unable to implement click listeners on that

Comment: Spannable / Html.fromHtml("dfkdfj <img src>...")  /

Comment: but how to implement click listener?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510940/android-multiple-clickable-strings-in-textview?rq=1

Comment: I want to set click listener on images not text

Comment: its the same, create ImageSpans

Comment: can you post some code I go through ImageSpan, clickablespan, etc but unable to find solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575438/how-to-add-click-action-for-the-imagespan

Answer (score 1):

Associate a Tag with each imageview and 
Set a common onclick Listner for both imageview in onclick even find the imageview by tag associated with View in onClick() method Like

Let two imageview are iv1 and iv2

```
     iv1.setTag("TAG1");
     iv2.setTag("TAG2');

            OnClickListener oc=new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                      String tag=(String) v.getTag();
                            if(tag.equals("TAG1"))
                         {
                                  // Imageview is iv1                                  

                               }else{
                             // Imageview is iv2                                  
                                    }
            }
        };
```

Try it and let me know if problem exist