# How to set multiple click on textview android

Tags: android, onclick, textview, onclicklistener

I want to set multiple click on textview. I see many answers but any answer can't help me. I make spanned string using this code:-

```
  private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(Html.fromHtml(deafultSpna + feelingSpan+tagfriendspan));
    ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(AddPostActivity.this, "hello click",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, 0, Html.fromHtml(deafultSpna).length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(AddPostActivity.this, "hello click ffff",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, Html.fromHtml(deafultSpna).length(), Html.fromHtml(deafultSpna+feelingSpan).length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(AddPostActivity.this, "hello click ffff fdsfds",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, Html.fromHtml(deafultSpna+feelingSpan).length(), Html.fromHtml(deafultSpna+feelingSpan+tagfriendspan).length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return ssb;
}
```

but using this code I found like this view:- 
[image: My layout look this]

But I want to like this:-

[image]

I make spanned using this code`feelingSpan = "<font color=#414141> - Feeling </font><font color=#bd2436>" + feeling_name + "</font>";`

Any one can help me so solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a little confused by your question. you have a textview..and you want to be able to click it a few times and each click does something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the part of the text view is clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable) and [How to click or tap on a TextView text on different words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584136/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text-on-different-words)

Comment: @DroiDev I want click on each span and this work fine but my each span color are same. I want to look like above image.

Comment: gotcha. wish i could help but i never did anything like that before. good luck.

Comment: Take a look at this answer
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable)

Comment: Try to Wrap your whole html in a <p>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510940/android-multiple-clickable-strings-in-textview

Answer (score 8):

To make things easier, we can start by defining a small class that will make the clickable spans red and show the appropriate message when clicked.

```
private class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    String text;

    MyClickableSpan(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setUnderlineText(false); // get rid of underlining
        ds.setColor(Color.RED);     // make links red
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Next, we can add a small convenience method to create the clickable spans.

```
private void addClickableText(SpannableStringBuilder ssb, int startPos, String clickableText, String toastText) {
    ssb.append(clickableText);
    ssb.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(toastText), startPos, ssb.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

Finally, we can fill the spannable string and display it.

```
    TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);

    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
    addClickableText(ssb, ssb.length(), "Abhishek Nagar", "hello click");
    ssb.append(" - Feeling ");
    addClickableText(ssb, ssb.length(), "Sad", "hello click ffff");
    ssb.append(" with ");
    addClickableText(ssb, ssb.length(), "Anand Jainb", "hello click ffff fdsfds");

    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());   // make our spans selectable
    text.setText(ssb);
```

And that's all there is to it!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        textView.setText(addClickablePart(getString(R.string.amanda_bio2)));
    }


    private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);

        ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "span clicked 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                ds.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }, 200, 214, 0);

        ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "span clicked 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                ds.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }, 241, 255, 0);
        return ssb;
    }
}
```

You can even add multiple spans and also customize its colors.

Answer (score 0):

I Have Created a generalized function for this purpose hope this helps

```
fun TextView.makeLinks(vararg links: Triple<String, View.OnClickListener,LinkProperties>) {

    try {
        val spannableString = SpannableString(this.text)
        for (link in links) {
            val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
                override fun updateDrawState(textPaint: TextPaint) {
                    super.updateDrawState(textPaint)
                    textPaint.isUnderlineText = link.third.isUnderlineText
                    textPaint.isFakeBoldText = link.third.isBoldText
                    textPaint.color = link.third.color ?: Color.parseColor(DCColorPicker.BLACK)
                }

                override fun onClick(view: View) {
                    Selection.setSelection((view as TextView).text as Spannable, 0)
                    view.invalidate()
                    link.second.onClick(view)
                }
            }
            val startIndexOfLink = this.text.toString().indexOf(link.first)
            spannableString.setSpan(
                clickableSpan, startIndexOfLink, startIndexOfLink + link.first.length,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        }
        this.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance() // without LinkMovementMethod, link can not click
        this.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "makeLinks: " + e.message)
    }
}
```

and you can add N no. of properties here

```
 data class LinkProperties(val isUnderlineText: Boolean = false, val isBoldText: Boolean = false, val color: Int?=null)
```

and for calling you can use this function like this

```
val linkBoldOnly = LinkProperties(isBoldText = true)
val linkBoldUnderline = LinkProperties(isUnderlineText = true, isBoldText = true)

binding.name.makeLinks(
Triple("text", View.OnClickListener { openMore() }, linkBoldUnderline),
Triple(name.toString(), View.OnClickListener { itemClick() }, linkBoldOnly)
)
```