# Create clickable links in a TextView in a ListView item

Tags: android, listview

I know there are lots of answers to this question but I cant seem to get it to work...
I have a ListView with some custom items consisting of TextViews and ImageViews.

I receive some data through an XML feed. One of the elements contains HTML like:

```
<![CDATA[ <p>My text <a href="http://myhost.com/link/to/fM" target="_blank">click here</a>.</p> ]]>
```

In my adapter I have this method:

```
private static Spanned fromHtml(String html){
    Spanned result;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        result = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        result = Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm on Android 6 so I end up in the "else" section.

I use a "holder" class to define all my TextViews and ImageViews needed for a ListView item. The holder instance is assigned like this:

```
view.setTag(myHolder);
```

and the TextView in question I populate like this:

```
String s = fromHtml(xmlItem.Description).toString();
myHolder.description.setText(fromHtml(s));
```

If I omit the

```
fromHtml(s)
```

and just setText(s) I get all the tags from my CDATA rendered

I really just want the text "click here" to be rendered as a clickable link...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

> ```
> String s = fromHtml(xmlItem.Description).toString();
> ```

The `setText()` method accepts anything that implements the `CharSequence` method. Most people usually pass `String` instances, which is totally fine since `String` implements `CharSequence`. But strings don't contain the information needed to handle links, so you should change that line to this instead:

```
Spanned s = fromHtml(xmlItem.Description);
```

`Spanned` also implements the `CharSequence` interface, so you can pass `s` to `setText()` just like before. And now you will see a highlighted link.

That's not the whole solution, though. You need your `TextView` to also know how to *handle* the link spans that `fromHtml()` creates. You use the `setMovementMethod()` call for this. You only need to call this once (e.g. when your `convertView` is null so you're creating a new view), but you should add this line as well:

```
myHolder.description.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: It works!!! Followed your advice and then also manually stripped the CDATA start and end tags. That did it! Thanks a million!

Comment: Just discovered that the item click event is no longer fired on my listView item :-/ Any solution to that?

Comment: @CJe so you want one thing to happen when the user clicks the link, and another thing to happen when the user clicks anywhere else? And are you using an `OnClickListener` on the view or an `OnItemClickListener` on the list?

Comment: Yes. Actually the link is hidden to begin with. Then when a user clicks the listView item an extra section (a description) is displayed. This description MAY contain a link. Clicking again should hide the description again.

Comment: @CJe I poked around a bit, and I'm sorry but I don't have an answer for this yet. It looks like the `MovementMethod` object is intercepting all clicks somehow...

Comment: Hmm... thanks for the effort tho :-) Clicking the link actually does close the listView again... maybe I can use that for something...

Comment: Got it working using https://stackoverflow.com/a/34200772/1480182. I had to use textView.setClickable(true); to prevent onItemClick() to be fired after onTouch()