# How to set multiple on click listeners on different words of textview?

Tags: android, string, dynamic, textview, clickablespan

Just how the facebook app does it. Multiple clickable texts in one textView.

I tried the FlowLayout and multiple texviews but still the texview shifts to another line when the text exceeds the width.
[image: Multiple clickable texts in one texview]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183645/android-clickablespan-in-clickable-textview

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya So I create spans for every tagged user right?

Comment: yes yes .That's better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Spannable String](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/Spannable.html)** are used in Android to highlight the particular portion of text with different click event in a **`Single TextView`**.

You can check **`#SO`** Demo for this

1. **[How to set the part of the text view is clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable)**
2. **[Android: ClickableSpan in clickable TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183645/android-clickablespan-in-clickable-textview)**

I hope it will helps you .

Comment: what is `SpannableTextView` ? there is no such thing in the SDK

Comment: @pskink  .Thanks for checking . sorry sorry . `SpannableString` .

Comment: Thanks alot @IntelliJAmiya